# TV output url title of resource id

Tags: modx, television

When I create a multi select input where i can select resources and I want the output to be a link to that resource. How can I get to link to read/show the title of the page i'm linking to? I can't find any info about that.

I've tried [[*pagetitle]], but then the link text is the pagetitle of the page i'm currently on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your TV outputs the id of the resource you want to link to, you can use [getResourceField](http://modx.com/extras/package/getresourcefield):

```
<a href="[[~[[*yourTV]]]]">[[getResourceField? &id=`[[*yourTV]]` &field=`pagetitle`]]</a>
```

More on how to use it here:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResourceField

Comment: I'm affraid I might need to do that. I was hoping I could put some hook or something in "Display Text:"

Comment: Nothing wrong with that at all, that's how it's done :) Also, it's cached so not going to affect performance. No idea what you mean by 'Display Text'

Comment: I will use your method if that's how it goes. Thanks. Display text is the field I can fill in that will function as the link text. It's the first field in output type URL

Answer (score 0):

try `[*pagetitle*]`  or `[*#pagetitle*]`.

first one should work fine.